# How do I define variables to pass data between JQuery and javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello again :) I have following code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(function () {
       $('body').on('click', 'a.myclass', function () {
           sndcmpnm = $(this).attr("value");
           alert("From Small Function :" + sndcmpnm);
       });
   });
});
</script>
```

In the page at the bottom, I have a simple javascript with the line `var deares = sndcmpnm;` The funny thing is that no matter what I do, `deares` never gets the value of `sndcmpnm`. I tried another solution from SO, which said I must not put `var` infront of the variable but that also did not help. The alert `alert("From Small Function :" + sndcmpnm);` gives the right result. The java error code thingy says

> ReferenceError: sndcmpnm is not defined

All I want is that `deares` can get the value of `sndcmpnm`. I don't see what I am doing wrong, please help me :(

**[EDIT]** Other code :

```
<script>
function discomp()
{
  alert("hello1");
  var deares = sndcmpnm;
  alert("hello2");
  alert("This is suppose to hold the sndcmpnm data :" +deares);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Where is your other code? Also, you have 2 DOM ready wrappers, you only need one. (And as a side note, jQuery *is* JavaScript - it's just a library)

Comment: The question title doesn't make any sense, jQuery is JavaScript.

Comment: please post full error source

Comment: hey @tymeJV : Added the other code :)

Comment: sorry, I haven't been using javascript for long. The full error code ? The only error I get is the one in the little java web console in firefox which says : " ReferenceError: sndcmpnm is not defined"

Comment: Where exactly do you write `var deares = sndcmpnm;`? If `sndcmpnm` is a global variable, then this shouldn't happen.

Comment: Seems like `discomp` is executed before the click event handler (and hence `sndcmpnm` is never set). Also, JavaScript has nothing to do with Java.

Comment: I think the problem is no one is clicking on the link! The event will not fire.

Comment: @FelixKling is correct, somewhere in your code the `discomp()` function executes before the click event callback on the body.

Comment: @jeanna.b Do you want `deares` to be the value of `sndcmpnp` when it is called (that is, to make a copy) or to update as `deares` changes?

Comment: That is correct in this case. In the actual page, it does get fired. Lets assume it does fire :) 

In the `$(document).ready(function () {}` I need to be able to create a variable, that I can draw a value from later , i.e below in the `discomp` function.

Comment: @soktinpk : Yes, `deares` should get the value of `sndcmpnp`. Problem is, `deares` is in the bottom javascript and `sndcompnp` is in the jquery script within functions :(

Comment: @jeanna.b Please see my answer below. It shows were you need to define  `sndcmpnp` for it to be available in `discomp()`.

Comment: `<a>` elements don't have an attribute `value`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define `sndcmpnm` in the global scope of the `script` tag. (And you only need one document ready, `$(function() { ... }` is a shorthand for `$(document).ready(function() { ... }`.)

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

var sndcmpnm = '';

$(function() {

    $('body').on('click', 'a.myclass', function() {

        sndcmpnm = $(this).attr("value") ;
        alert("From Small Function :" + sndcmpnm);

    });

});

</script>

<script>
function discomp() {
  var deares = sndcmpnm;
  alert("This is suppose to hold the sndcmpnm data: " + deares);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, almost ! Thank you. Just that it gives output for deares now "undefined". If `alert(sndcmpnm)` then it shows "undefined".

Comment: It shouldn't. But when exactly is `discomp()` being called?

Comment: @jeanna.b: `<a>` elements don't have an attribute `value`.

Comment: @jeanna.b Sorry, had to set `sndcmpnm` to something for it not to be undefined anymore. It was accessible as it should though. And as @FelixKling pointed out, `<a>` tags don't have the attribute `value`. So what information is it you wish to get from the `<a>` tag exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You could call the `discomp` function from within the event handler:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function discomp(message)
{
  alert("This is suppose to hold the sndcmpnm data :" + message);
}

$(function () {
    $('body').on('click', 'a.myclass', function () {
        var sndcmpnm = $(this).attr("value");
        discomp(sndcmpnm);
    });
  });
});
</script>
```